# Kruskal's MST : Union operation using Union-Find DS: Guarantee on join taking place between the nodes with least edge weight

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-algorithm

In the Minimum Spanning Tree, we require to join the edges with minimum weight before we move on to other edges. To perform the join we use the union operation of the UF DS, which joins the representative elements of the disjoint data sets. Is there a guarantee that the representative elements will be the nodes with least edge weight that we intend to join? The join could very well take place at other nodes of the components to be joined, if I am thinking this right.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no such guarantee. Fortunately, Kruskal's uses the disjoint-set data structure to maintain the connectivity of the edges scanned so far, and the representatives don't matter for this purpose. If you want the tree structure in the end, you need to do something different (DFS on the set of edges, sub a dynamic tree for the disjoint-set data structure so that you can join the actual endpoints, use Prim's instead).

Comment: So, if I intend to calculate the minimum sum of edges for the MST (using Kruskal's), I need to do it during the Joining phase rather than at the end. Otherwise, there seems to be no utility for Kruskal's vis-a-vis Prim's.

Comment: @RutuparnDalvi Yes.